# I have a problem with the 9.2 version of kettle

Tags: kettle

When using the kettle cluster, an error was reported for the conversion data, and the error format is as follows:
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1- ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1 - This step will block all incoming rows until at least all defined steps finish! You must define at least one step.
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1-
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.blockuntilstepsfinish.BlockUntilStepsFinish.processRow(BlockUntilStepsFinish.java:71)
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2021/12/29 10:28:57 - step1-    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021/12/29 10:28:57 -step1 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)

Comment: Do you have a Step that is made to wait for something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.